# Npgsql exception on connection string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, nuget, npgsql

I cant get Npgsql connection string to work. I've tried some ways, for example

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.220;User Id=pgsql;Password=pgsql;Database=pgsql;");
```

or

```
var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=192.168.1.220;Username=pgsql;Password=pgsql;Database=pgsql");
```

both throws me exception:

> The type initializer for 'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder' threw an exception.

Im running Windows XP 64bit with VS 2010. I've already tried to connect from that machine to my pgsql server using ODBC or pgAdmin III - both works ok.

Could be this problem related to my Npgsql installation?
I was not able to install it with NuGet, because I got following error:

> PM> Install-Package Npgsql
>   Installing 'Npgsql 3.2.1'.
>   Successfully installed 'Npgsql 3.2.1'.
>   Adding 'Npgsql 3.2.1' to Project.
>   Uninstalling 'Npgsql 3.2.1'.
>   Successfully uninstalled 'Npgsql 3.2.1'.
>   Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Install-Package : Could not install package 'Npgsql 3.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client', but the packag
>   e does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Npgsql
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I've tried also to switch target framework to 4.0 or 3.5, but result was exactly the same.
So I installed Npgsql simply by extracting .dll from MSI installation, then load it as reference.

Does anyone know how to make connection string to work?

Comment: From your nuget installation exception, it would seem like you're trying to install Npgsql into a .NET Framework 4.0 project - this isn't supported. The lowest supported version is 4.5.

Comment: If you still get the exception in a .NET 4.5 (or later) application, please post the full exception you're getting, include the full stack trace and any inner exceptions. It's not possible to know what's going on with just "The type initializer threw an exception".

Comment: It seems that problem has been exactly as you descibed, but I need .NET 4.0 to make it run on WinXP, so, I solved my problem by switching from Npgsql to Devart basic pgsql library. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about the port. Maybe this is the cause. The standard PostgreSQL server listening on port 5432.

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.220;Port=5432;User Id=pgsql;Password=pgsql;Database=pgsql;");
```

[Example Connection String](https://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/)

Maybe you haven't a library **Mono.Security.dll**. It is necessary in the older version less then 3.0 or is enabled the system firewall?

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it doesnt help, I got same error. Firewall is disabled and im able to connect to server from this machine using pgAdmin ||| or ODBC.

Comment: Maybe you haven't a library Mono.Security.dll. It is necessary in the older version less then 3.0.

Comment: The Port isn't mandatory, Npgsql will use port 5432 by default.